# SQL Workbench WbExport to two locations for Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

Is it possible to export to two locations using WbExport for Redshift. Or is there an alternative method without having to change the file path.

```
WbExport -file = 'file_path1'
-type=text
-delimiter=,
-header=true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible with SQL Workbench/J

You need to run two WbExport commands with different file names.

An alternative is to run it once, then use [WbSysExec](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/wb-commands.html#command-wbexec) to copy the generated file to the second location